# what is the different between dynamodb and dynamodb stream?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, consistency

what is the different between dynamodb api and dynamodb stream api? why add dynamodb stream?

For example, if I want operator two or more tables of dynamodb action together,
I mean for instance like payment, if I want to make sure the money attribute of account and the payment invoice have data consistency.Does dynamodb stream can do it?

I mean payment invoice table and account table should have operation together, can I make these action as stream of operation and do it together?

Can you give me example of how to do these operation on Dynamodb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DynamoDB Streams enables a read-only view of the actions that have been performed against DynamoDB tables. Think of streams as analogous to a Kinesis stream that provides an audit of all writes to the tables. Streams does not provide the ability to enforce atomicity on writes to tables, but could be used for monitoring after the fact that the sources are out of sync. The best I can see for transactional storage within DynamoDB is in the [AWS Developer Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/performing-conditional-writes-using-the-amazon-dynamodb-transaction-library/), but it is from 2014 so it may be outdated.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2014/11/10/introducing-dynamodb-streams/
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB is the database itself, and DynamoDB stream gives the ability to capture changes to items stored in a DynamoDB table, at the point in time when such changes occur. so it is like a database trigger. You can utilize these changes stream by capture a specific event and take action. DynamoDB stream events can be accessed and processed using AWS Lambda for example.